# Spring on Wildfly not rendering index.html when root URL hit

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss

Due to project requirements I have to deploy a Spring application to a server incapable of running Tomcat and only capable of running WildFly. When I had a very simple project running on Tomcat and the root URL was hit `(localhost:8080)` it rendered my `index.html`. Since migrating to WildFly and refactoring the structure of my project, `localhost:8080` no longer renders the `index.html` but I *can* still reach other URLs.

I've tried to implement a `jboss-web.xml` file under `BrassDucks/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` like this:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>Brass-Ducks</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Where `Brass-Ducks` is the `artifactID` but to no avail.

Consider my `ApplicationConfig.java`

```
package brass.ducks;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApplicationConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfig.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<ApplicationConfig> applicationClass = ApplicationConfig.class;



}

@RestController
class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello/{name}")
    String hello(@PathVariable String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

and consider my `Controller.java`

```
package brass.ducks.application;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping("/greet")
    @ResponseBody
    public String greeting() {
        return "Hello, there.";
    }
}
```

And finally should it be relevant, my folder structure:

[image: hierarchy]

`localhost:8080/greet` returns "Hello, there" and `localhost:8080/hello/name` returns "Hello name". How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post your web.xml file?

Comment: @GergelyBacso Ooh, I don't have one of those...

Comment: Ok, that is going to be Spring doing things for you. Would you consider simply adding an extra Controller, mapping the `/` path to index.html?

Comment: Supposing I was to change my greet method and my index.html was in WebContent, what would I write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your exact configuration something along the lines of this should work:

```
@Controller
public class LandingPageController {

@RequestMapping({"/","/home"})
public String showHomePage(Map<String, Object> model) {
    return "/WEB-INF/index.html";   
   }
}
```

This is going to explicitly map `/` to `index.html`.

Comment: This returns the String `/WEB-INF/index.html` on the page, rather than the actual HTML page.

Comment: You do not have any resolvers configured then? (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver)